# Unable to format the date in Handlebars.java using {{now}}

Tags: java, handlebars.java

I am trying to render the present date using Handlebars in Java. While using the `{{now}}` handlebar, I am able to print the date as "Dec 8, 2017":

```
<ul>
 {{#items}}
 {{name}}

     {{now}}

 {{/items}}
</ul>
```

But when I try to format the date by passing a parameter, I am getting a `null` value. Am I doing something wrong here? -

```
<ul>
 {{#items}}
 {{name}}

     {{now ["full"]}}

 {{/items}}
</ul>
```

Comment: What programming language did you use @Vishnu?

Comment: Hey @MacStevins, this is a simple "Hello World" type experiment where I tried to render a HBS file using the data from a JSON file. More on Handlebars: https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java

Comment: String helpers on page: https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java/blob/master/handlebars/src/main/java/com/github/jknack/handlebars/helper/StringHelpers.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of Handlebars, but you may need to specify the format in there?

```
{{now ["format"] [DateFormat.FULL]}}
```

Otherwise [this](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java/blob/master/handlebars/src/main/java/com/github/jknack/handlebars/helper/StringHelpers.java)  would be a good place to look.

Comment: Hey @Tristan, adding the format did not help me as well - anything other than `{{now}}` returns a null value

Comment: for the sake or of argument could you try something like  **{{now format="yyyyMMddHHmmss"}}**

Comment: Good!  I'm not sure why the import of the **DateFormat.FULL** didn't work though.